# Help with a SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm looking for a SQLite query which will return values that are great or less than 0.014763 for the lng and 0.008830 for the lat. I'm using the following code...

```
 $latupp = $_REQUEST['currlat'] + 0.008830; 
 $latlow = $_REQUEST['currlat'] - 0.008830;
 $lngupp = $_REQUEST['currlng'] + 0.014763;
 $lnglow = $_REQUEST['currlng'] - 0.014763;
 $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tweets` 
                       WHERE `lat` > $latlow AND
                             `lat` < $latupp OR 
                             `lng` >  $lnglow AND
                             `lng` < $lngupp;") or die(mysql_error());
```

But it's returning incorrect results e.g results greater or less than 0.1441209. I can't quite figure out why. does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How have you defined "lat" in the database -- looks like a floating point precision issue.

Comment: Yeah, both 'lat' and 'lng' are fields in the database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps...

```
 $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tweets` 
                       WHERE `lat` > $latlow AND
                             `lat` < $latupp AND 
                             `lng` >  $lnglow AND
                             `lng` < $lngupp;") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 5):

That should work:

```
 $latupp = $_REQUEST['currlat'] + 0.008830;  
 $latlow = $_REQUEST['currlat'] - 0.008830; 
 $lngupp = $_REQUEST['currlng'] + 0.014763; 
 $lnglow = $_REQUEST['currlng'] - 0.014763; 
 $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tweets`  
                       WHERE `lat` BETWEEN $latlow AND $latupp   
                             AND
                             `lng` BETWEEN  $lnglow AND $lngupp;") or die(mysql_error());
```

Maybe you need parenthesis to separate the first and second part (Can't test it here).

You made a little mistake by connecting the lat and the long constraint with an "OR". Your command says:

Give me all records which have:

- a lat value greater than $latlow AND
  lower than $latupp, NO MATTER what
  long value it has got

OR

- a long value greater than $lnglow AND
  lower than $lngupp NO MATTER what lat
  value it has got

OR BOTH

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tweets` 
                       WHERE `lat` >". $latlow. "AND
                             `lat` <". $latupp. "OR 
                             `lng` >".  $lnglow. "AND
                             `lng` <". $lngupp.";")
```

Comment: Its maybe related about AND/OR keywords usage priority. You use them with brackets